# Fit ImageSpan to TextView line height

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, drawable

I need to put some icons inside my textview, but they don't fit the line height (look at the arrows):

[image: screenshoot]

I tried this:

```
spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, entry.getValue(), ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM), Matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
t.setText(spannable, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

and this:

```
    Drawable myIcon = c.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myicon);
    myIcon.setBounds(0, 0, myIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), myIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
    spannable.setSpan(new ImageSpan(myIcon, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
t.setText(spannable, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

and in both cases i had the same result.

I keep the icon in /res/drawable folder, and its size is 75x75px.
I tried to lower the image resolution but they look blurred

Comment: try myIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 20) or something, 20 should really be line height

Answer (score 31):

You need to set the image's bounds to the TextView's line height.  Eg:

```
myIcon.setBounds(0, 0, t.getLineHeight(),t.getLineHeight());
```

This of course assumes you want a square image.  If not square, then you'll need to manually determine what the width value should be based off the line height.

Comment: The height won't exactly be the same, and your text will have a small offset. See Andrew's answer above.

Answer (score 4):

To achieve correct height of included into textview drawables you should set them appropriate bounds. But firstly, we have to calculate them correctly. Especially its height.

After some experiments I realized that `FontMetricsInt` field from `Paint` class can be useful.

```
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
//obviously, we have to set textSize into Paint object
textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
FontMetricsInt fontMetrics = textPaint.getFontMetricsInt();
setBounds(
        0,
        fontMetrics.ascent,
        widthForDrawable,
        fontMetrics.bottom
);
```

So, the top of our image is aligned using `ascent` value of `FontMetricsInt` and the bottom - with `bottom` value.

Comment: Thanks! Just an addition: if you are displaying a squared image, the "widthForDrawable" can be replaced by fontMetrics.bottom - fontMetrics.ascent .